# Command to Cleanse a .csv file in unix

Tags: bash, csv, unix

I have a csv file like

```
 abc,qwe,qwe,
 addadf,dfsgsfg,sdgsdg,
 adfsg,sdgsfg,sgsfg,
 ,,,,,
```

I have to parse the file in a way such that i don't get those blank lines with commas at the end

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` for this job:

```
grep -v "^[,]*$" <filename>
```